# Is 眩しい思いで referring to a feeling or a memory?

Tags: meaning, words, syntax

I'm wondering if 眩しい思いで in the following is referring to a memory or a feeling:

> その背中を、眩しい思いで見つめていた。
>
> He gazed at their backs with dazzled feeling/He gazed at their backs dazzled by a memory.

I'm confused is the 思い supposed to mean feelings/thoughts here with で particle following it or is it actually referring to 思い出 which refers to memories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 「その背中{せなか}を、眩{まぶ}しい思{おも}いで見{み}つめていた。」

It is 「思い」 + particle「で」.

If it were 「思い出」, that part would make no sense.  Even if it made sense, you would still need to use a word or phrase between 「思い出」 and 「見つめていた」.